# Laravel mix doesn't generate a correct manifest

Tags: webpack, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I have the following directory structure:

```
resources/
   assets/
       images/
           background/
           icons/
           slider/
           favicon.png
           logo.png
```

Within the `webpack.mix.js` I have this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['!robots.txt', '!index.php', '!sitemap.xml']
    })], stats: 'error-only'
})
    .setPublicPath('public')
    .setResourceRoot('/assets/vendor/boilerplate')
    .version()
mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/images', 'public/images')
```

When I run `npm run dev` I get this `mix-manifest.json`:

```
{
    "/images/favicon.png": "/images/favicon.png?id=0e779c5b9015ad6661cde56026b8f8c1",
    "/images/logo.png": "/images/logo.png?id=44907894ea066629ec18e8a09f378c06",
}
```

but I have image also in the subdirectory `background, icons, slider`, why does `laravel-mix` didn't included all the files of the subdirectories?

Comment: I'm facing same problem. All files from copyDirectory are in mix-manifest.json. Did you solve it?

Comment: @general666 I specified the sub directories manually using `copyDirectory`, I guess is the only way to achieve this at the moment.